# How to get windows phpmyadmin databases (.SQL) backup from Ubuntu?

Tags: mysql

My  windows10 is not starting up but I have installed Ubuntu along with windows.

I have some mysql databases in my windows environment which I need backup so is there any way to open windows version of the databases in ubuntu so I can export that databases.

Comment: If they're both MySQL servers, then use `mysqldump` to download the file, and then you can import to another server.

Comment: mount the windows file system in ubuntu and copy the mysql files over to an ubuntu file, and start mysql on ubuntu, then export them with mysldump, as aynber suggests. forget phpmyadmin - that is just a web based interface

Answer (score 0):

after handling JoSSte above comment you need to run these command in terminal

```
mysql -u user_name -p   this command will ask for password
```

after successfull above command , you can check your database using below command

```
show databases;
```

if your database is there you can export database using below command

```
mysqldump -u your_db_user_name -p [database_which_need_to_export] > database_name.sql
```

this command will give you sql file then you can import it using command or in phpmyadmin

Comment: This will not work because the MySQL Server and databases are in the Windows environment and Windows will not start up, and so MySQL will not be running. Read the question more carefully.

Comment: @ADyson i write answer how he can export db if and only if he can see his db , he should follow JoSSte comment first.

Comment: " i write answer how he can export db"...yes I understand that perfectly. But you can't export a database from a server which isn't running...you seem to have totally missed that point. The Windows O/S won't start up, so it's not possible to run the server. Therefore your suggestion can never work, it doesn't provide a solution to the problem. You are describing a process for the wrong situation.